# vue environmental variables return empty object

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am new to vue and webpack, When I console.log(process.env. VUE_APP_API_URL) in my vue application, an empty object returns. I have a .env.development file with:

```
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000/api
```

The application backend is built in laravel which works fine. But I want to be able to store the api url as an environment variable.

My webpack.config.js

```
     var path = require('path')
     var webpack = require('webpack')
     module.exports = {
     entry: './src/main.js',
     output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
     publicPath: '/dist/',
     filename: 'build.js'
     },
     module: {
     rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
    },
    resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
    },
    performance: {
    hints: false
    },
    devtool: '#eval-source-map'
     }

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      },
    }),
     new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    }),
    ])
    }
```

I tried running npm install dotenv-webpack --save-dev and add it the webpack plugins but it still didnt resolve the issue.
How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the configuration from your .env file you need to first install the dotenv dependency, and call `require("dotenv").config()` before calling your variable. This will load the variables and make them available using `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLES`

Comment: I tried adding this to the main.js and I got n error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in....

Comment: "fs" is a node module to access the file system, you should not have this dependency in your vue project.